# Will the data fall into the system if I modify the design of the form in the code on my website?

Tags: forms, sidebar

If I modify the code on the page myself (e.g., changing the width of the form, or the font) will the data still fall into SalesManago?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of modification of the appearance of the form in the code on the site, these changes will not be visible in the system, that is, the appearance of the form in the system will remain as it was before the changes, but it will not affect the data falling into the SM. All the logic related to data submission does not change, the important thing is that you do not change the attributes in the elements, e.g. name, id, ect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).